# Handling choosing the wrong serial port in upgrade software

Tags: c#, validation, serialization, input, serial-port

I have firmware upgrade program that updates the software on a device through a serial connection. This will be sent to clients who will perform the upgrade. In testing, I found that COM1 can be selected and will open even without a serial cable connected. 
There is code to check if the connection is open and also to catch exceptions, but since COM1 is opening, the program just continues though there is no connection to the device.

**How do I handle a client choosing the wrong COM port?**

There will be instructions provided, but I would feel safer having this problem handled by the app.

Here is my serial port open code:

```
// Create a new SerialPort object.
        SerialPort _serialPort;
        _serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, 115200, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

        // for state machine
        bool _continue = true;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort.Open();

                if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Serial Port is Open");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Serial Port is not open. Choose another port.");
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        } while (!_serialPort.IsOpen);
```

Comment: Don't do a loop and you will be OK, just try to open the port and if it throws an exception inform the user and let him to choose another one.

Comment: Also, I suppose you have some form of protocol with a handshake of some form, so you can program a timeout, if the device doesn't answers in X time close the port and inform the user.

Comment: The IsOpen test never fails, you called Open before that.  You did not test this, it simply doesn't work.  Serial ports are too crude to have a reliable "is connected" test.  The DsrHolding property can help but is no guarantee.  Be sure to have an Option menu that allows the user to select the correct port number.

Answer (score 0):

In the mid 2000s, I worked with a company that programmed GPS devices. We programmed that via USB to serial communication, as we had to program a large amount of devices at one time. The device itself had a method of sending a request/response type of message, so we could see what ports were connected to a device. I would look at the device you are programming and see if it has that concept. If so, you can iterate any serial ports on the machine on inform the user which have devices on them.

If it is possible a user can use a USB to serial device, it gets a bit trickier, as USB devices do not discover in the same order every boot up. Our solution was to examine devices connected to USB ports seeking the USB to serial device. It was a bit crude, as you examine the device information to determine it is USB to serial and then iterate the serial ports. We were using multiple 8, and later 16, port devices connected to USB.

Hope this helps.